# Online algorithm for reduced row echelon form

Tags: algorithms, gaussian-elimination

## Rough Definition of "Online Algorithm"

In computer science an [online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) is used to calculates a function of a set, but is fed its inputs incrementally instead of at once. As a rule they retains some sort of state which is bounded in size (rather than simply a set of all values seen up to that point).

If $f(x_1, \ldots, x_t)$ is the function to be evaluated at time $t$, then there should be some function $g$ and some sequences of states $(s_i)$ such that
$$(f(x_1, \ldots, x_t), s_{t+1}) = g(x_t, s_{t})$$

## Simple example of Online Algorithm

Here is an example using the average of a set of the numbers in Python2

```
state = {'total': 0, 'step': 0}
while True:
    x = float(raw_input()) # get a number from the user
    (avg, state) = g(x, state)
    print avg
```

Where g is defined as

```
def g(x, state):
    state['total'] = state['total'] + x
    state['step'] = state['step'] + 1
    avg = state['total'] / state['step']
    return (avg, state)
```

## Online algorithm for reduced row echelon form

A system of linear equations over the variables $\bar{x}$ can be thought of as a set of linear equations of the form $\bar{a} \cdot \bar{x} = b$.

I was wondering if there is a standard approach for streaming the linear equations so that at time $t$ the program is provided with $(\bar{a}_t, b_t)$ and calculates the current reduced row echelon form for all equations seen.

The most obvious solution is letting the state be the reduced row echelon form of all the equations known up to that point. When the new equation is introduced it is included it in the system of equations encoded in the reduced row echelon form and the program updates it state by gaussian elimination.

But this approach seems wasteful, and I am wondering if there is a smarter way to introduce the new equation.

I admit the state of this algorithm grows with the number of inputs. But it is bounded by the square of the number of variables of the overall system and does not grow unbounded with respect to the number of equations.

Comment: I suspect that any online algorithm is bound to be unstable, since you cannot do pivoting.

Comment: @J.M. is that to say that the introduction of a new row into the previous RREF matrix might ruin the previously calculated partial results?

Comment: I suspect that the amount of state which you propose to save cannot be reduced by more than a constant factor.  However it is within a constant factor of the size of input, in the worst case.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible, unless you can guarantee conditions like diagonal dominance or SPD.

Comment: @hardmath `the amount of state which you propose to save cannot be reduced by more than a constant factor` Is this true if there is a constant number of variables, and we are assessing grown in terms of the number of equations? You seem to be talking about a trivial encoding of all the equations seen so far, which can easily incorporate new equations even if the latest one might be linear combinations of the previous ones? I guess how to do this is the real question, and I will have to calculate RREF on the trivial encoding. Furthermore I would guess that this encoding uses a matrix.

Comment: My thought was to consider the space required by $t$ reduced row-echelon rows.  If the input rows have length $n$ and half are linearly independent, then we need to account for  $(t/2)\times (n-(t/2))$ entries in columns without leading ones.